# EditText - setText on EditText with inputType=numberPassword doesn't show the 'set' text first before the password char

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm creating a PIN dialog that contains multiple EditText. The behavior I want to achieve is, when the user enter a character, it gets to be shown first before being masked with EditText's password character (bullet/dot).

Instead of managing the multiple EditText, I have a hidden view (EditText) that handles the keyboard input. It's text will then be set to the other EditText that serves as the pin view. However, when I set the value for the pin from the hidden view, the password character is being set right away, no more preview of the set value. The behavior is different when I tried to enter a character directly to the pin view.

How can I achieve the behavior I want with the this current setup? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Can also Achieve This behavior By just using one **Editext**.

On User Keypress show Current Character for 1 second while all entered characters are shown **`*`** if entered.Then replace all text with `*`,with the length of Text enter inside **Edittext**.

Basically Toggling The Visible Character with * after 1 second while holding real password inside a variable and then hiding newly entered character by replacing Edittext text with * of variable.length.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't what I want to do. Prior to entering the PIN, I'm showing an image for each pin view, like a hint. I believe I won't be able to achieve it if only one EditText is used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what I wanted isn't possible. From what I'm doing the cursor moves to the next EditText when the current received a value.

Using an EditText with inputType (in my case) numberPassword, as soon as the focus was removed from the EditText or if it doesn't have the focus in the first place, setting a value to it will immediately show the 'password' character.